# content over flow in flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a footer I got three divs for three columns and set container display on flex and flex divs set to 1 to be equal columns but when I put a paragraph inside it it goes outside container

```
.footer{
    background: #303036;
    color:#d3d3d3;
    height:400px;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .footer-content{
    display:flex;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:350px;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section{
    padding: 20px;
    flex:1;
    border:1px solid white;
}

        <div class="footer">
              <div class="footer-content">
                  <div class="footer-section about">
                  <h1 class="logo-text"><span >V</span>Tech</h1>
                            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

                  </div>
                        <div class="footer-section links"></div>

                        <div class="footer-section contact-form"></div>


              </div>


        </div>
```

Comment: You are set `height` (`400px` and `350px`), remove it and height will be fit.

Answer (score 0):

> **Just remove height**

```css
.footer{
    background: #303036;
    color:#d3d3d3;
    position: relative;
}

.footer .footer-content{
    display:flex;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.footer .footer-content .footer-section{
    padding: 20px;
    flex:1;
    border:1px solid white;
}
```

```html
   <div class="footer">
              <div class="footer-content">
                  <div class="footer-section about">
                  <h1 class="logo-text"><span >V</span>Tech</h1>
                            <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

                  </div>
                        <div class="footer-section links"></div>

                        <div class="footer-section contact-form"></div>


              </div>


        </div>
```